# How can I match string that have repeated characters repeated a certain number in a range?

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I need to substitute every strings composed of 2 to 5 repeated character

Is there a more compact expression than this

```
$ echo a aa aaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaaa| sed 's/a\{2\}/word/;s/a\{3\}/word/;s/a\{4\}/word/;s/a\{5\}/word/;' 
a word word word word aaaaaa
```

For instance by giving the range the curved bracket (does not work) `\{2|3|4|5\}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do:

```
sed -E 's/\b([[:alpha:]])\1{1,4}\b/word/g'
```

- `\b` matches word boundary
- `([[:alpha:]])` matches any alphabetic character in current locale, and put that as captured group 1
- `\1{1,4}` matches the captured group 1 to 4 times i.e. in total, the character is being matched 2 to 5 times
- if matched, the word is replaced with string `word`
- the `g` modifier of substitution (`s`) replace all such occurrences of words

To match any character, not just alphabetic, replace `[[:alpha:]]` with `.`:

```
sed -E 's/\b(.)\1{1,4}\b/word/g'
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo 'a aa aaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaaa' | sed -E 's/\b([[:alpha:]])\1{1,4}\b/word/g'
a word word word word aaaaaa
```